# Gradle generate Eclipse project EAR project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, ear

I'm migrating a legacy project from `ant` to `gradle` (to use its dependency management and build features) and I'm facing a problem when generating the `eclipse` projects. The big problem today is because the project has some subprojects that are split into `war` and jar packages to deploy into a single `ear`. This is made by `ant` today.
To use `gradle` I split the `eclipse` projects into separate `jar` and `war` projects.
So I have the following structure:

```
ProjectRoot
-lib
-Project1.jar
-Project1.war
-Project2.jar
-Project3.war
```

**And here's my `gradle` file**:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
def jboss_home = '/home/augusto/Development/servers/jboss6X' 
def deploy_name = 'default'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
}

dependencies {
    deploy project(path: 'Project1.jar', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: 'Project1.war', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: 'Project2.jar', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: 'Project2.war', configuration: 'archives')
    earlib fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}

ear {
    libDirName = "lib"
    deploymentDescriptor {
        applicationName = "MyApp"
        initializeInOrder = true
        displayName = "MyApp"
        module("Project1.jar", "java")
        module("Project2.jar", "java")
        webModule("Project1.war", "/Project1")
        webModule("Project2.war", "/Project2")
    }
}

project('MyJarLib') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile files('../lib/ajar.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: jboss_home + '/common/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: jboss_home + '/client', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: jboss_home + '/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: jboss_home + '/server/' + deploy_name + '/lib', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

project('Project1.jar') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.2-FINAL', 'jdom:jdom:1.1'
        compile project(':MyJarLib.jar')
    }
}

project('Project1.war') {
    apply plugin: 'war'
}

project('Project2.jar') {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:3.7.0', 'jdom:jdom:1.1'
        compile project(':MyJarLib.jar')
    }
}

project('Project2.war') {
    apply plugin: 'war'
}
```

I've put the `ear` plugin in the sub projects to deploy it to server using `eclipse`. If I let just jar, I cannot deploy it to server using eclipse (and I want to do this to use the hot deploy feature from jboss 6). Our team has big productivity problem to maitain this application because of `ant` builds. It takes almost 15 minutes to test a feature because they can't use hot deploy...
The problem with `eclipse`: it does not generate a single `ear` in its deploy. It deploys the packages separately and the server fails to deploy.
The problem with the `gradle` build: it is generating the right structure, but it is creating `application.xml` files inside each jar project (because of the ear plugin). I use only the root `application.xml`. Can you help me solve both this problems? Thanks.

### EDIT

I've managed to make eclipse deploy my project right using the tips in the comments. In all java projects I've put this configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
ear.onlyIf { false }
ear {
    //appDirName 'src/main/java'
    libDirName '../lib'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src/main/application'
    }
    }
}
eclipse.wtp.facet {
    facet name: 'jst.ejb', version: '3.1'
    facet name: 'java', version: '1.6'
}
eclipse.classpath.file{
    withXml {
    def nodes = it.asNode().children().findAll{it.@kind == 'lib'}
    nodes.each {
        if(it.attributes[0] == null)
            it.appendNode('attributes').appendNode('attribute', [name:'org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency', value: '../lib'])
        else
            it.attributes[0].attribute[0].@value = '../lib'
    }
    }
}
```

I've put the ear plugin, so gradle generates the project ready to deploy in eclipse. The `ear.onlyIf { false }` makes gradle not generate the artifact in ear structure. After this I've changed the eclipse preferences to set the facet of the project to EJB and changed the classpath entries to deploy the dependencies in the ear lib directory instead of the root of the ear. My problem now is in the build from gradle. When I call `gradle ear` it is generating lots of dependency errors due the fact that the web container library is not in the classpath... So I have a lot of classnotfound exceptions. If I put all the classes as dependencies from my project, it will mess with the eclipse classpath (and deploy). The question is: Is there a way to provide a provided dependency for java projects in gradle and is there an easy way to provide all those jars from jboss instead of each one?

Comment: You should only apply the `ear` plugin to the project that produces the ear, not to the projects that produce wars/jars. This could be its own subproject or the root project. In any case, you need to apply the `eclipse` and `eclipse-wtp` plugins to `allprojects { ... }`.

Comment: Ok. But how can I use the generated project to deploy to server through eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure how much of that is set up automatically, and how much you need to set up yourself (either manually or by customizing the project generation).

Comment: I want the team to get the project from subversion, call gradle eclipse, add the project to jboss on eclipse and hit run

Comment: And gradle build to generate a deployable package to production

Comment: The Eclipse part might take some customization (not sure). In any case, first you'll have to fix the build as I've explained above. Then you can give it another run.

Comment: ok... but how to build in a strutcture that I can deploy from eclipse?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If deploying from Eclipse doesn't work out-of-the-box, and you nevertheless want to automate the setup, you'll have to figure out which XML to generate, and then use the appropriate hooks of the `eclipse` plugin to do so (check the samples in the `gradle-all` download).

Comment: Deploy from eclipse DOES work out of the box. It does not work out of the box on the projects I've created from gradle. I've already checked the samples and used them to create my project. The problem is gradle does not generate the projects in the right structure to deploy from it. It does not generate for example the appplication.xml from the root project, so my projects are deployed independently from each other

Comment: Projects created from Gradle is what I'm talking about. Until the build script has been fixed according to my feedback and the question updated accordingly, it's impossible to help further.

Comment: ok... removed the ear from the projects and it does not fixed anything or solve anything.

Comment: Plugins are still applied to the wrong projects.

Comment: can you be a litle more specific about which one is wrong?

Comment: Check my first comment.

Comment: It generated an eclipse project for the root but it did not generate the buildpath for the subprojects... Eclipse cannot compile the project.

Comment: All I can say is that this usually works fine. Perhaps try with a simplified build, to rule out other problems. Also, don't apply the `ear` plugin to the root project.

Comment: I've managed to make the eclipse part work but I can't build the project from gradle :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make all work. Using the workarounds in my edit part of the question and some points of this [article](http://www.sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/). Here's what I have to do:

```
configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
    compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    compileClasspath += configurations.compile
    compileClasspath += configurations.runtime
    java {
        srcDir 'src/main/application'
    }
    }
}
```

This made possible to use provided in the dependencies of all my projects and it does not mess with the eclipse project.